# How to find records by month Datamapper

Tags: datepicker, sinatra, datamapper

In my project I need to have ability ti add reports.
Adding a report user can choose date for placing his report. (not created_at)
I save this data in "Date":DataTime - format column(2012-03-24T00:00:00+00:00)
User selects date from datepicker and than i parse it with `DateTime.parse(2012-03-24)` and than save to DB.
Than user via datepicker selects a month.
How can I correctly perform a query to  find all records for perticular month?
Is there any method to find by month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You should calculate margin dates and use `:date => range` (it will create sql BETWEEN query). For example:

```
month = params[:month].to_i
date_a = DateTime.new Date.today.year, month, 1
date_b = (date_a >> 1) + 1  # will add a month and a day
Page.all :updated_at => date_a..date_b
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Now when I have those records filtered, how can I organize cycle to show records grouped by each day of that month

Comment: (date_a >> 1) + 1 - nice trick, but my knowledge is to poor to understand it. Once again big big thanks, you helped me alot!

Comment: `date >> n` and `date << n` are extremely useful when you wants to add or subtract some months, and you don't know how many days in those.