# Finding Records From This Month Datamapper with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I'm building a little Sinatra web app at the moment and having problems understanding queries with DataMapper.

I have a field in my database which I've called date, I'd love to query this and only return records from this current month.

I've tried this:

> query = "2012-11"
>
> @trips = Trip.all(:date.like => '%query%')

Which doesn't seem to work, I'm hoping someone might spot my error and give me some guidance! Hope someone can help, thanks for taking the time to read.

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a range instead:

```
@trips = Trip.all(:date => (query..query))
```

I'd also fix your date format and provide month, day and year.

Comment: Will this bring back all the records from a specific month? I was hoping I could just use some kind of wildcard like 2012-11-* to return all the entries. I'm not sure how to automatically find the start date and end date of a given month so I was hoping to work around it using a wild card?

Comment: You'll need a date range for date queries. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862123/how-to-find-records-by-month-datamapper for how to calculate the dates if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
require 'date'

date_c = Date.today
next_y, next_m = date_c.month == 12 ?
  [date_c.year+1, 1] : [date_c.year, date_c.month+1]
date_a = Date.new(date_c.year, date_c.month)
date_z = Date.new(next_y, next_m)

Trip.all :date => date_a..date_z
```

this will return current month entries

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply! Any tips on how to calculate these fields automatically based on the current date?