# datamapper, how do you filter a date field by month and year?

Tags: ruby, datamapper

using datamapper, how do you filter a date field by month and year?

I can filter all records with today's date.

```
:date => Date.today
```

but i am curious if there is an elegant solution 
for returning all records from december 2012.

```
posts.all
+----+------------+
| id | date       |
+----+------------+
| 1  | 2009-10-20 |
| 2  | 2012-11-18 |
| 3  | 2012-12-10 |
| 4  | 2012-12-14 |
+----+------------+

posts.all(:date => Date.today)
+----+------------+
| id | date       |
+----+------------+
| 4  | 2012-12-14 |
+----+------------+
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find records by month Datamapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862123/how-to-find-records-by-month-datamapper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use the date range form (which will result in an SQL "BETWEEN" query):

```ruby
posts.all(:date => (Date.parse('2012-12-01') .. Date.parse('2012-12-31')))
```

For other years/months you'll have to lookup or compute the last date of the month instead of hardcoding them as in the example above.

```ruby
def month_range(year, month)
  d0 = Date.parse([year, month, 1].join('-'))
  (d0 .. (d0>>1)-1)
end
posts.all(:date => month_range(2012, 12))
```